# ORACLE SQL select values from XML

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

How can I select values from XML in ORACLE SQL?

Let's say I have two XMLs in table "items":

first row and column "intreevalue" data

```
<change xmlns="http://do.it.com/ch/PLP">
  <header>
    <op>XDD</op>
  </header>
  <id>10565</id>
</change>
```

and
second row and column "intreevalue" data

```
<deactivate xmlns="http://mrlo.com/nnu/XCBouIK">
  <header>
    <op>XDG</id>
  </header>
  <id>67544</id>
</deactivate>
```

I know "EXTRACTVALUE" is depricated. I need values "op" and "id" in one select. I guess if there is no namespace like 'xmlns="http://do.it.com/ch/PLP"' it would be easy. But can I select data like this (example - I know it can't work, just trying to say what i mean)?

```
select "/*/header/op" op, "/*/id" id from .....
```

Thanks

Comment: Look here, this may help: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=dynamic-sql-in-regular-sql-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options:

1. Use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` to remove all `xmlns` attributes from all tags.

   ```
   SELECT EXTRACT(XMLTYPE(REGEXP_REPLACE(items.intreevalue,
                                         '(<[^>]+[[:space:]]+)xmlns(?::[^[:space:]=]+)?[:space:]*=[:space:]*"[^"]*"',
                                         '\1')),
                  '/*/header/op/text()')
          .GETSTRINGVAL() op,
          EXTRACT(XMLTYPE(REGEXP_REPLACE(items.intreevalue,
                                         '(<[^>]+[[:space:]]+)xmlns(?::[^[:space:]=]+)?[:space:]*=[:space:]*"[^"]*"',
                                         '\1')),
                  '/*/id/text()')
          .GETNUMBERVAL() id
          FROM items;
   ```

   But it might be a problem if you actually need to treat some elements from different name spaces differently. Maybe you can then tweak the regular expression to remove only "problematic" name space attributes but keeping others.
2. Use a large `CASE ... END` to check each possible namespace and take the first one you get a (not `NULL`) result for.

   ```
   SELECT CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(items.intreevalue,
                         '/*/header/op/text()',
                         'xmlns="http://do.it.com/ch/PLP"')
                 .GETSTRINGVAL() IS NOT NULL
              THEN EXTRACT(items.intreevalue,
                           '/*/header/op/text()',
                           'xmlns="http://do.it.com/ch/PLP"')
                   .GETSTRINGVAL()
            WHEN EXTRACT(items.intreevalue,
                         '/*/header/op/text()',
                         'xmlns="http://mrlo.com/nnu/XCBouIK"')
                 .GETSTRINGVAL() IS NOT NULL
              THEN EXTRACT(items.intreevalue,
                           '/*/header/op/text()',
                           'xmlns="http://mrlo.com/nnu/XCBouIK"')
                   .GETSTRINGVAL()
          END op,
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(items.intreevalue,
                         '/*/id/text()',
                         'xmlns="http://do.it.com/ch/PLP"')
                 .GETNUMBERVAL() IS NOT NULL
              THEN EXTRACT(items.intreevalue,
                           '/*/id/text()',
                           'xmlns="http://do.it.com/ch/PLP"')
                   .GETNUMBERVAL()
            WHEN EXTRACT(items.intreevalue,
                         '/*/id/text()',
                         'xmlns="http://mrlo.com/nnu/XCBouIK"')
                 .GETNUMBERVAL() IS NOT NULL
              THEN EXTRACT(items.intreevalue,
                           '/*/id/text()',
                           'xmlns="http://mrlo.com/nnu/XCBouIK"')
                   .GETNUMBERVAL()
          END id
          FROM items;
   ```

   If there is a namespace not included in the case you'd still get `NULL`s for the respective XML.

Comment: I need to process them in the same way. So the first answer is really perfect for me and works flawlessly. But the second one will be good in other cases. Thank you very much!!